# Filter unique results to reduce the number and order those results by most recent Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have a data set from which I want o filter some data. I have managed to query the data I want which includes selecting where the date is. The problem is that I need to take the formula a little further so that I limit the number of results returned (in specific columns - L, M) to 3 and order by the most recent.

The formula I have at the moment looks something like this:
My formula in I1 is

```
={
query(Sheet1!D2:H, "SELECT * WHERE E MATCHES 'East' and D > date'"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and D <= date '"&TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"); 
query(Sheet1!D2:H, "SELECT * WHERE E MATCHES 'West' and D > date'"&TEXT(B3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and D <= date '"&TEXT(C3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'") 
}
```

The link to my doc is
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a_iUWKF4C0rFdaiHKZKbt1wrWySbWLLWUBiGvLjAKbE/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you included a sample a small input and desired output. Because you say unique between L and M, but do you mean the combination, or to treat each row as two rows because they have two names? Include this sample in the question, not the external sheet.

Comment: Can you please clarify what result you expect, given the sample data you are showing?  When you say "Col A, B, C contain my filtering dates" does that mean return records from the East where column D (Date) is >= 2020-05-01, and <= 2020-07-30, and records from the West where column D (Date) is >= 2020-06-01, and <= 2020-09-30?  And just the three latest records?  Or the three latest records for each Rep?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({SORT(QUERY({DATEVALUE(D2:D), E2:H, IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, A2:C, {2, 3}, 0))}, 
 "where Col1>Col6-1 and Col1<Col7+1", 0), 1, ), COUNTIFS(
 INDEX(SORT(QUERY({DATEVALUE(D2:D), E2:H, IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, A2:C, {2, 3}, 0))}, 
 "where Col1>Col6-1 and Col1<Col7+1", 0), 1, ),,2), 
 INDEX(SORT(QUERY({DATEVALUE(D2:D), E2:H, IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, A2:C, {2, 3}, 0))}, 
 "where Col1>Col6-1 and Col1<Col7+1", 0), 1, ),,2), ROW(INDIRECT("E2:E"&COUNTA(
 INDEX(SORT(QUERY({DATEVALUE(D2:D), E2:H, IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, A2:C, {2, 3}, 0))}, 
 "where Col1>Col6-1 and Col1<Col7+1", 0), 1, ),,2))+1)), "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("E2:E"&COUNTA(
 INDEX(SORT(QUERY({DATEVALUE(D2:D), E2:H, IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, A2:C, {2, 3}, 0))}, 
 "where Col1>Col6-1 and Col1<Col7+1", 0), 1, ),,2))+1)))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col8 < 4 format Col1 'yyyy-mm-dd'", 0))
```

[image]